# nginx location alias stop redirect

Tags: html, redirect, nginx

I have following `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes      1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include             mime.types;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;

  sendfile on;

  keepalive_timeout   65;

  server {
    listen            8080;
    server_name       localhost;
    index             index.html index.htm;

    location /docs {
      alias            /usr/share/nginx/html;

      if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
          #
          # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
          #
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
          #
          # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
          #
          add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
          add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
          add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
          return 204;
      }
      if ($request_method = 'POST') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
      }
      if ($request_method = 'GET') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

nginx is running in docker. Traefik acts as proxy and redirects on `/docs` path into the nginx container (to port 8080). Here nginx container should simply return the content (static content).

My problem is that nginx always redirects me to `http://api.example.com:8080/docs/` (which is not accessible because I run nginx in docker behind traefik, thats why I need the path). I simply try to get the HTML content from the html directory under `https://api.example.com/docs`.

Additional output:

```
10.0.5.16 - example [11/Aug/2018:17:30:45 +0000] "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36"
```

How to just serve content under `../docs` Url without this redirections, which are wrong?

Comment: The URI `/docs` points to a directory. The default behaviour is to add a trailing `/` to it. Is there a specific file within the `docs` directory, that you would like returned instead?

Comment: i just need to return index.html (it's within html, there is no docs directory)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the external redirect, you could use an internal rewrite from `/docs` to `/docs/index.html`.

For example:

```
location = /docs {
    rewrite ^ /docs/index.html last;
}
location /docs {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this helped for me(break after rewrite and second location for any files):

```
  location = /docs {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    rewrite ^ /docs/index.html break;
  }
  location /docs {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
```